# Binding onmouseover Event To Multiple Elements In Array

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small JavaScript game.

The code I'm looking at is this bit:

```
cells[i].onmouseover = function() {
        cells[i].style.top =
        (cells[i].getAttribute('data-top') - 25).toString() + "px";
    }
```

Each cells[i] element is a member of an array of `<img>` elements.

Currently, whenever I hover over an img element it generates the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

I can't work out what's going on. Why is `cells[i]` undefined?

Here's all the potentially relevant code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < mapSize; ++i) {
    cells[i] = document.createElement('img');
    cells[i].src = 'base1.png';
    cells[i].class = 'base1';
    cells[i].id =  'cell' + i;

    game.appendChild(cells[i]);

    row = Math.floor(i / mapWidth);

    top = tops[i%mapWidth + row];
    left = lefts[mapWidth + (i % mapWidth) - row];

    cells[i].setAttribute('data-top',top);
    cells[i].setAttribute('data-left',left);

    cells[i].style.top = top.toString() + "px";
    cells[i].style.left = left.toString() + "px";
    cells[i].style.zindex = i;

    console.log(cells[i]);

    cells[i].onmouseover = function() {
        cells[i].style.top =
        (cells[i].getAttribute('data-top') - 25).toString() + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the dup to know what's happening, but I suggest you use event delegation.

Comment: Thank you! This is interesting.

Comment: Please note that `onclick` will only support a single event function. `addEventListener` allows multiple events to be attached to an element.

Comment: The duplicate is somewhat relevant, but really addresses a different situation. The solutions presented there are not what you would use here. In your case, the element to which the handler is bound will be available as the `this` value, so if that was the only reason for using the `i` value, then instead you'd just do this: `this.style.top = (this.getAttr...`

Comment: Thank you cookiemonster, that's perfect! I was actually pretty close to that, but for some reason was trying alternate versions of this and cells[i], which obviously didn't work. In other words, conceptually I was still miles away from your answer! Thanks a lot, really appreciate it - the dupe question was really cool as well.

Comment: @JimmyM: You're welcome. And yeah, the other Q/A is certainly worth remembering. It's almost guaranteed to  be relevant at some point.

Answer (score -3):

This should work...

```
cells.each(function(key, index){
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.mouseover(function() {
        var top = _this.data("top") - 25;
        $(this).css("top",top);
    });
})
```

Comment: Where is this magic jQuery coming from..?

Comment: Oh, and also, "this should work" is not a good explanation of your code.

Comment: Not to mention that it isn't a correct use of `.data()`, or that your own code shows that the `_this` variable is unnecessary.